# Game Center memory deallocation (with Cocos2D)

Tags: memory, cocos2d-iphone, center, memory-leaks

We've just added Game Kit to our Cocos 2D game. It works fine, but causes some serious memory leaks. I've read all posts about it on this forum (and on other forums), but nothing seems to help. We're using the GameCenterManager from GKTapper.

This is how we create the leader board and show it:

```
-(void)showLeaderBoard:(NSString *)lb withScore:(int)score
{
GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

if (leaderboardController != nil){
gcVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
leaderboardController.category = lb;
leaderboardController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeWeek;
leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview: gcVC.view];
[gcVC presentModalViewController:leaderboardController animated:YES];
}

}
```

And here it's removed:

```
- (void)leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController
{
[gcVC dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[gcVC.view.superview removeFromSuperview];
[gcVC release];
}
```

The leak is obvious if you look at the used Real Mem in the activity monitor. The first time the leader board is shown and dismissed the app's memory usage has increased with 11.42MB, then it increases with ~0.3MB every time the leader board is shown and dismissed. Also, every time you browse between "Today", "This Week" and "All Time" in the game center leader board another ~0.2MB are eaten up.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that code is old and was used before cocos2d added its own RootViewController. Here's the code that I'm using in [KKGameKitHelper](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/Kobold2D/html/interface_k_k_game_kit_helper.html):

```
-(UIViewController*) getRootViewController
{
    return (UIViewController*)((KKAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).rootViewController;
}

-(void) presentViewController:(UIViewController*)vc
{
    UIViewController* rootVC = [self getRootViewController];
    [rootVC presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
}

-(void) dismissModalViewController
{
    UIViewController* rootVC = [self getRootViewController];
    [rootVC dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

// Leaderboards

-(void) showLeaderboard
{
    if (isGameCenterAvailable == NO)
        return;

    GKLeaderboardViewController* leaderboardVC = [[[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    if (leaderboardVC != nil)
    {
        leaderboardVC.leaderboardDelegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:leaderboardVC];
    }
}

-(void) leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController*)viewController
{
    [self dismissModalViewController];
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(onLeaderboardViewDismissed)])
    {
        [delegate onLeaderboardViewDismissed];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this Cocos2D or Kobold2D?  I've never seen KKAppDelegate before... (using Cocos2D 1.1).

Comment: That's from Kobold2D but should work with any app delegate. Just change the cast and make sure the app delegate has the rootViewController exposed as property.